# Is Wordpress Suitable for my site?

Tags: wp-admin

I will be starting the development of a site that will allow my users to upload pictures and giving the ability to other people to view them. I just want to know if wordpress is suitable for all these things (payment system, editing the user profiles) because i hear all the time that wordpress is mostly for blogs, but my site has nothing to do with a blog.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: There are a considerable number of WordPress sites that are **not** blogs, and I'm not talking about similar things like news sites

Comment: WordPress is suitable for **everything**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably mostly a preference thing, but I don't think Wordpress is a great solution for sites outside of content creation. In my opinion, one of the weakest parts of Wordpress is how they handle images and galleries. We are building a completely custom interface for creating galleries on our application because it's so cumbersome.

In addition to just photo/gallery management, payment systems are all handled through 3rd party plugins. So they are fairly cumbersome in themselves.

In my opinion, from what you've explained Wordpress is probably not the right choice, but there are tons of other options like joomla and drupal.

Comment: I agree with this 100%, one thing that WordPress does not excel at as a CMS is for is user based media management. Sure you can integrate something into WordPress but you would be writing most everything from scratch.

Comment: I too agree, i'l throw another CMS into the ring that i think is ideal for what the OP is looking for http://www.silverstripe.org/

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to do what you want with WordPress, given some development time.

I'd advise you look into gravity forms. For uploading from the frontend you can look elsewhere on this site, as it's one of the most commonly asked questions.

If you're totally new to WordPress you may want to find someone more experienced and knowledgeable before starting development ( the same can be said of all the other CMS' too ).